# Comparison between select then filtering and select distinct in linq, c#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Which is faster?

Getting a list of some variable (say `string` type) from a LINQ and then filtering duplicates in C#, or directly `selecting distinct` values in LINQ only?

Say we are having

> N rows if we take duplicates
>
> and R if we filter
>
> ( N >> R ) there are many duplicates.

Basically I am asking, in general which is faster and better programming

- selecting whole N rows in LINQ, convert it into a list and then filtering it to R rows
- or directly selecting the R rows from LINQ and converting it to a list.

Note :

IN SQL the time taken to get R rows is roughly 2 times then it takes to get N for my case! But a generic answer is welcome.

Comment: I suppose you could Benchmark......

Comment: A generic answer is not possible, unless you count "it depends". You will need to run benchmarks on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume when you say Linq, you mean LinqToSQL.

Rule of thumb when connect to database is to only get what you need; and for this, if you have a good querying strategy for Linq, then filtering at LinqToSQL can save a lot of wasted work.

If the column you're filtering happens to be FullTextIndex, you hit the jackpot.

Answer (score 1):

Look, you question is complex, what i mean.

1)Better programming is to use the most of times a ready build-in function

2)Based on my experience Distinct works faster, in MsSql and C#.

3) LINQ is kinda lazy on filtering, especially if you have many items in your list. [Distinct](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ed38539f-fde4-4a2a-8e80-d058c32b332b/linq-select-distinct-c) is optimized by Microsoft developers.

note: similar [question](http://bytes.com/topic/oracle/answers/912959-how-efficient-queries-use-distinct-vs-filtering-data-yourself), may be useful

Result: Try to use more of build-in functions you have at your platform, there is a plenty of information on net, and you can escape paragraphs of coding just calling a ready function.

Hope it helped.